# Display url of article in facebook comment notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, blogs

I have a blog with facebook comment plugin attached after each post. I also configured my facebook app to recieve notification whenever users leave any comment on my post. BUT, my notification only shows that user leaved a comment without any link to that post, so it's very hard to know exactly which post has been commented.

Is there any way to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#faq to use the `comments.create` edge of the JS SDK's `FB.Event.subscribe` function.

> **How do I know when someone commented on my site?**
>   You can subscribe to the 'comment.create' and 'comment.remove' events in the Facebook SDK for JavaScript through FB.Event.subscribe.

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.0#comments-example The `response` object should contain the data you want. You could then trigger an ajax call for instance to let a service of yours know that a comment was made.

Comment: I did, but it shows notification without link to my post